# PSQL Regex match transforming many to one

Tags: regex, postgresql

How can I transform the results of this query:

```
select regexp_matches('number: 772392 number: 911604 number:123456',  '[0-9]{6}', 'g');
```

From this:

```
{772392}
{911604}
{123456}
```

To this?:

```
{772392,911604,123456}
```

I've tried transforming it via *array_to_string*, and *array_agg*, but I haven't been successful.

```
select array_to_string
(array_agg(regexp_matches
('number: 772392 number: 911604 number:123456', '[0-9]{6}', 'g')), ', ');
```

Comment: Any of those would work fine. It's more about concatenating them into a single cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regexp_matches` returns set of **text arrays**

> If the pattern contains no parenthesized subexpressions, **then each row returned is a single-element text array** containing the substring matching the whole pattern.

so you should

```
select string_agg(numb[1], ', ') 
    from regexp_matches('number: 772392 number: 911604 number:123456', '[0-9]{6}', 'g')
    as numb;
```

to achieve your goals